# PHP/MYSQLi Bind Result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bind-variables

I'm writing for a web, that does not have mysqlnd.  So I need to quickly change all my code to not use it.  I thought I was there with this function, but it repeats results.

I would really appreciate any help as to the fix.

```
function getDBResults($sql, $params=array()) { // param 1 sql, param2 array of bind parameters
    $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_DATABASE);
    if (!is_array($params)) {
        $params = array($params);
    }

    $query = $con->stmt_init(); // $this->connection is the mysqli connection instance

    // Start stmt
    if($query->prepare($sql)) {

        if (count($params)>0) { // Skip of there are no paremeters
            // This will loop through params, and generate types. e.g. 'ss'
            $types = '';                        
            foreach($params as $param) {        
                if(is_int($param)) {
                    $types .= 'i';              //integer
                } elseif (is_float($param)) {
                    $types .= 'd';              //double
                } elseif (is_string($param)) {
                    $types .= 's';              //string
                } else {
                    $types .= 'b';              //blob and unknown
                }
            }
            array_unshift($params, $types);
            // Bind Params
            $bpArray = array($query,'bind_param');
            $bpArray = 'mysqli_stmt_bind_param';

            array_unshift($params, $query);

            $tmp = array();
            foreach($params as $key => $value) {
                $tmp[$key] = &$params[$key];
            };

            call_user_func_array($bpArray, $tmp); 
        }

        $query->execute(); 

        // Get metadata for field names
        $meta = $query->result_metadata();

        // initialise some empty arrays
        $fields = $results = array();

        // This is the tricky bit dynamically creating an array of variables to use
        // to bind the results
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
            $var = $field->name; 
            $$var = null; 
            $fields[$var] = &$$var; 
        }

        // Bind Results
        call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_result'),$fields);

        // Fetch Results
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) { 
            call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_result'),$fields);
            $results[] = $fields; 
        }
        $query->close();
        // And now we have a beautiful
        // array of results, just like
        //fetch_assoc
        return $results;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just debug it?

Comment: what do you mean?

Im new to php/mysql - this is the php web ive had to write so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: I mean [debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging)

Comment: I cannot see why it doesnt work, thats why I am asking for help.  I dont ask before looking.  Im sorry but I really dont find your answer helpful. (I asked what you mean incase you were refering to some specific debugging feature I may have been unaware of)

Comment: I would rather say that it is *occupation* you choose it trolling you as it turned to be not a rose garden you were thinking of.

Comment: First, this is not an answer, but a *comment*. Second, debugging *is* a technique used by programmers to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: BTW, if you are new to php/mysql, then let me suggest you to use PDO instead of mysqli, as it doesn't have none of the latter's problems - neither with binding variable number of params, nor with binding results.

Comment: thanks for the PDO suggestion, I have seen that.  Im concerned about its availability (on the host being used).  Before this week I didnt even know there were so many connectors/drivers for mysql/php.  I really am a complete newbie to it

Comment: I have to say that your attempt is quite awesome for someone who is new to the business - most of codes posted here are way silliest. But honestly, doing debugging all day round on my job, I don't feel like doing the same on a weekend, and doing it "mentally", by means of reading code (as real debugging require *running* it). But what I wanted to say is that "being stuck" is a *regular* state for the programmer - there is nothing special in it.

Comment: Thank you, I know too well.  The problem is I am just unfamiliar with bind  results - I code with different languages but usually stuck with old Classic ASP and VBA.  I wouldnt be asking if it wasnt the combination of a Monday deadline and my sons birthday tomorrow.  Not that its your problem.  Also I cant claim full credit, its a frankenstein like creation of three another dynamic parameter scripts :) .

Comment: Just give PDO a try. as I said above, it doesn't have none of the problems this frankenstein is intended to solve. I'll show you the code

Comment: Ok will give it a try, looking at other answers its a bit of a panacea it seems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getDBResults($sql, $params=array()) {
    global $pdo; // you should NEVER connect in a function! But use already opened.
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

see - three simple lines.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) is all the info you need. Just remember you have to connect only once per application and use this connection all the way.

Comment: it's just because mysqli is actually a raw API but PDO is a higher-level library that already have methods for all the general purpose tasks. Once *can* build one upon mysqli, but it will take time

Comment: Thanks, tested on host seems to support PDO, what a relief.

Comment: Just to add, I know we "got off on the wrong foot" - I really appreciate your answer.  So simple I wish I knew about PDO days ago... as I'm rewriting my libs for it, the code is a fraction of its original size - its almost 'elegant' now in places :)